# Using GROUP BY in mysql giving syntax error

Tags: mysql, syntax, group-by

I have this query:

```
select * FROM `posters` p
INNER JOIN `poster_logs` pl ON pl.`pos_id`= p.`id`
WHERE pl.`log` = 'Accepted' AND p.`book`='book1' AND
p.`category`='category1'
ORDER BY p.`category`, p.`id`
```

That returns to me a poster_logs.pos_id several times and I dont want this so I tried to add "group by pl.`pos_id`" in this way:

```
select * FROM `posters` p
INNER JOIN `poster_logs` pl ON pl.`pos_id`= p.`id`
WHERE pl.`log` = 'Accepted' AND p.`book`='book1' AND
p.`category`='category1'
group by pl.`pos_id`
ORDER BY p.`category`, p.`id`
```

But that gives me a syntax error and I dont know what I'm doing wrong. I'm really beginner with SQL.

Comment: show error here what you getting

Answer (score 2):

What version of MySQL are you using?

Your current query:-

```
SELECT * 
FROM `posters` p
INNER JOIN `poster_logs` pl ON pl.`pos_id`= p.`id`
WHERE pl.`log` = 'Accepted' 
AND p.`book`='book1' 
AND p.`category`='category1'
GROUP BY pl.`pos_id`
ORDER BY p.`category`, p.`id`
```

is not using any aggregate fields (but as you have used SELECT *, not a clue which fields it is returning).

Older versions of MySQL do support this , although it is against SQL standards except in certain limited circumstances.

Newer versions of SQL have support for this turned off by default, although you can set an option to enable it:-

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html

*MySQL 5.7.5 and up implements detection of functional dependence. If the ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY SQL mode is enabled (which it is by default), MySQL rejects queries for which the select list, HAVING condition, or ORDER BY list refer to nonaggregated columns that are neither named in the GROUP BY clause nor are functionally dependent on them. (Before 5.7.5, MySQL does not detect functional dependency and ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY is not enabled by default. For a description of pre-5.7.5 behavior, see the MySQL 5.6 Reference Manual.)*

With your current query, if it worked then it would bring back 1 row per pos_id, but which row the other columns come from is not defined. Normally you would want a specific row (maybe the first, maybe the last).

Comment: I want all the colums from table posters but if a poster appears 2 times in the table poster_logs, then I have  the same poster twice, and I dont want to.

Comment: @JuanLopez in this case there is no point doing a `select *`. You need to decide what data you wanna grab from the `poster_logs` table per poster. We can't figure that out instead of you.

Comment: So if a post appears twice in poster_logs, there will be 2 rows of details. Which row do you want? Or do you just not care about any of the details from post_logs, just whether there is a matching row? It is generally a bad idea to use SELECT * in actual live code